# Вывести обьекты с ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Human> human = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    human.add(new Human(HumanName, lastName, middle_name, date, id));
}
human.forEach(System.out::println);
```

место полей мне выводит 100 хешкод объектов. Как сделать чтобы поля выводились объекта?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно переопределить метод `toString()` в классе `Human`, в нем вернуть строку, которую вы ходите получить. `IntelliJ IDEA` умеет генерировать `toString()` автоматически, для этого нужно нажать `Alt + Insert` -> `toString()` и выбрать нужные поля.

Answer (score 2):

@katso правильно отметил что нужно для объекта переопределить метод `toString()`.

Но удобнее использовать не автогенерацию кода intelij, а библиотеку [lombok](https://projectlombok.org). В ней есть много аннотаций для генерации шаблоного кода(геттеры, сеттеры, конструкторы, toString, equalsAndHashCode и т.д.).

Например [генерация метода toString](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString).

Плюс ломбока в том, что дополнительный код он создает на этапе компиляции, то есть при добавлении новых полей в классах, ничего не нужно дополнительно приписывать.